# Подсветка краёв изображения в ImageView

Tags: android, view, imageview

Добрый день. У меня есть картинка, которую я помещаю в `ImageView`. Картинкой является некая геометрическая фигура, её форма напоминает овал. Собственно вопрос, возможно ли каким-то образом сделать подсветку контура самой картинки (background border color), а не элемента `ImageView`, в который я и помещаю свою картинку?

Comment: подсветку​ при клике ?

Comment: @pavlofff нет, именно статичная рамка по контуру изображения. Её смысл в том, что она меняется в зависимости от ситуации. (Если пользователь онлайн - её цвет зелёный, если пользовать оффлайн - красный)

Comment: В общем то самое простое решение не мудрить подстветки, а нарисовать две фигуры: овал с зеленой подсветкой и с красной. При изменении статуса менять готовые картинки в `ImageView`.

Comment: @pavlofff Да, я думал об этом. а какие есть непростые решения? Хотелось бы более углубленно разобраться в этой теме. Что почитать посоветуете?)

Comment: может что то [вроде этого](https://android--examples.blogspot.ru/2015/11/android-circular-bitmap-with-border-and.html). Или с [методом `setShadowLayer()`](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/catshop/setshadowlayer.php) поработать. Я бы не стал искать сложных решений, если есть простые.